# Count and Sum functions with help of ViewBag

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, viewbag

I have a question how to solve my problem. There is a table with items. Each item has a status "open" or "closed". For instance, 9 items with "closed" status and 14 ones with "open". I need to find the difference between open and closed items (`14 - 9 = 5`). How can I do it with help of `ViewBag`? As I understood, it is required to write "count" function in controller and transmit the result to View via `ViewBag`. But I don't know how to write this code. The result should be shown on the View page.

Request.cs (Model):

```
public class Request
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = "";
    public string Status { get; set; } = "";
}
```

Controller.cs:

```
public IActionResult Requests()
{
    var Requests = _repo.GetAllRequests();
    return View(Requests);
}
```

Repository:

```
public Request GetRequest(int id)
{
    return _ctx.Requests.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);
}

public List<Request> GetAllRequests()
{
    return _ctx.Requests.ToList();
}
```

View:

```
<div>
    <table>
        @foreach (var request in Model)
        {
        <tr>
            <th>@request.Name</th>
            <th>@request.Status</th>
        </tr>
        }
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would pass a predicate to `Count` to filter the requests by status:

```
public IActionResult Requests()
{
    var requests = _repo.GetAllRequests();

    ViewBag.OpenRequests = requests.Count(r => r.Status == "open");
    ViewBag.ClosedRequests = requests.Count(r => r.Status == "closed");

    return View(requests);
}
```

However, rather than using the `ViewBag` you could create a view model to hold all the information/data required by the view:

```
// ViewModel
public class RequestViewModel
{
    public List<Request> Requests { get; set; }
    public int OpenRequests { get; set; }
    public int ClosedRequests { get; set; }
}

// Controller
public IActionResult Requests()
{
    var requests = _repo.GetAllRequests();
    
    var viewModel = new RequestViewModel();
    viewModel.OpenRequests = requests.Count(r => r.Status == "open");
    viewModel.ClosedRequests = requests.Count(r => r.Status == "closed");
    viewModel.Requests = requests;

    return View(viewModel);
}

// View: set the model for the view
@model Project.Namespace.RequestViewModel
...
<div>
    <div>Open Requests: @model.OpenRequests</div>
    <div>Closed Requests: @model.ClosedRequests</div>
    <div>Difference/delta: @(model.OpenRequests - model.ClosedRequests)</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    private StatisticScore()
    {
        var openCount =_ctx.Requests.Where(m=> m.Status == "Open").Count();
       var closedCount = _ctx.Requests.Where(m=> m.Status == "Closed").Count();
        ViewBag.Difference  = openCount  - closedCount 
    }
```

---

```
  <label> Difference </label> @ViewBag.Difference
```

Also, I suggest you; Do not use status fields as strings. It will be easier for you if you keep it as an enum.